# Not able to downcast a dynamic to a List<int> when used on a Map

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's start with:

```
dynamic list = [1];
var ints = list as List<int>; // Works
```

I am downcasting `dynamic` typed `list` to a type of `List<int>` and it works. Now, let's take another example:

```
var jsonString = '{"0": [1]}';
var Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(jsonString);
dynamic list = map['0'];
var ints = list as List<int>; // Fails
```

This time I am doing the same thing, `list` is of type `dynamic` and I'm downcasting it to `List<int>` but it fails with an error:

> `'List<dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type `'List<int>'` in type cast.

Can anyone tell me why first code works but second fails?

---

**Note**: I am not looking for a solution on how to make 2nd code work, I know how to do that. The question is in 1st code `dynamic` can be downcasted to `List<int>` but in second it can't be. Why is that so?

Comment: If I am downvoting an answer, I definitely expect those users will downvote this post too. but if you're one of them who didn't answer and downvoting it, I'd love to hear the reason behind your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why first code works but second fails?

The first code, you already *have* a `List<int>` (or maybe a `JsArray<int>` that implements `List<int>`). So typecasting works.

The second code, you do *not* have a `List<int>`. You have a `JsArray<dynamic>` that implements `List<dynamic>`. But that cannot be typecast into a `List<int>`. Because it simply isn't.

If you want to know why a `List<dynamic>` is not a `List<int>`, think of it that way: a List of animals is not a list of wolves. There could be sheep in it, too. If you want to have a list of wolves, you will have to *convert* the original list, not just *typecast* it.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see which types you're getting by printing the runtimeType

```
dynamic list = [1];
print(list.runtimeType);
var ints = list as List<int>; // Works
```

And

```
var jsonString = '{"0": [1]}';
var Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(jsonString);
dynamic list = map['0'];
print(list.runtimeType);
var ints = list as List<int>; // Fails
```

But it has probably to do with `[1]` being recognised as a `List<int>` which obviously can be casted to `List<int>`. But because your map is `<String, dynamic>` it could be any type in `map['0']` and that cannot be casted.

You could always make it work by using `List.from()`

`List<int> ints = List.from(map['0']);`

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/List/List.from.html

Comment: @iLoveDocs I added to my answer

Comment: `because your map is <String, dynamic> it could be any type in map['0'] and that cannot be casted`, that's why I am using `dynamic` typed for the `list` in 2nd code and so do I in 1st case. One is eligible for `List<int>` and other's not, that's the question!

Comment: @iLoveDocs This is as far as my educated guess goes. I have found a discussion on the dart github on casting which might be intersting https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736